# Trimmed NURBS in Web Browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, three.js, webgl, nurbs

How could one render a trimmed NURBS Surface in a web browser?

Three.js discarded adding this feature in 2015 ([Issue #3726](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3726)). Some people say that trimmed NURBS can be rendered using pure WebGL, but the details have never been discussed publicly.

Comment: Threejs only focuses on making it easy to draw meshes. All you really need to do is compute the triangles that make up the surface of the mesh. Start by making a plane, subdivide it, then make a function that returns Y given XZ coordinates on the plane.